# Parallel Server - Is it better to spawn a new per-connection handler, or spawn a new accepting process? (Rather than looping)

Tags: tcp, server, erlang

I'm reading the "Using TCP" chapter of "Software for a Concurrent World", and the parallel TCP server confuses me.

Rather than looping and spawning a new handler process for each connection, it spawns a new *acceptor* process – i.e. it continuously spawns copies of itself.

```
%% Parallel TCP Server (From the book)

par_start(Port) ->                                                                       
    {ok, Sock} = gen_tcp:listen(Port, [{packet, line}]),                             
    spawn(fun() -> par_connect(Sock) end).

par_connect(Sock) ->
    {ok, Conn} = gen_tcp:accept(Sock),
    % Spawn a new process to accept more connections
    spawn(fun() -> par_connect(Sock) end),
    handle(Conn).

handle(Conn) ->
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, Bin} ->
            io:format("Data: ~p~n", [Bin]),
            gen_tcp:send(Socket, Bin),
            handle(Conn);
        {error, closed} ->
            io:format("Connection closed: ~p~n", [Conn])
    end.
```

I find this bit confusing:

```
par_connect(Sock) ->
    {ok, Conn} = gen_tcp:accept(Sock),
    % Spawn a new process to accept more connections
    spawn(fun() -> par_connect(Sock) end),
    handle(Conn).
```

Is there a benefit to handling the connection in the process that accepts it, rather than spawning a new handler for each connection?

Spawning new handler for each connection:

```
connect(Sock) ->
    {ok, Conn} = gen_tcp:accept(Sock),
    % Handle connection in different process
    Handler = spawn(fun() -> handle(Conn) end),
    gen_tcp:controlling_process(Conn, Handler),
    % Loop to accept more connections
    connect(Sock).
```

It does avoid a call to `gen_tcp:controlling_process(..)`. Is it faster to skip this, and instead spawn a new process?

Comment: Yes, it is. you're right.